# Как сделать меняющийся фон по нажатии кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Например: я нажимаю на кнопку и у сайта меняется цвет фона, или меняется логотип в шапке, или же просто меняется дизайн сайта (цвет кнопок, цвет меню и фон), возможно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаем `color-1.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: #ffe5e5;
}
```

Создаем `color-2.css`:

```
body {
    background-color: #e5e9ff;
}
```

Создаем `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="color-1.css" data-style="styles">
</head>
<body>

<div class="colorbox" attr-css="color-2">Color-2</div>
<div class="colorbox" attr-css="color-1">Color-1</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.colorbox').on('click',function(){
    var link = $('link[data-style="styles"]');
    var stylesheet = $(this).attr('attr-css');
    link.attr('href', '' + stylesheet + '.css');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Запускаем, кликаем на текст `Color-2` - фон должен поменяться, потом на `Color-1` - фон должен вернуться в исходное положение. Принцип ясен, вот так и делать.

Comment: И будет шустрее, если `color-*.css` будут содержать `root` переменные, а использоваться они будут в в общем `styles.css` – https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 0):

В php не знаю, а вот в JS нативный метод `elem.classList.toggle("class")`, но 
если класса `class` нет, добавляет его, если есть – удаляет.